# C#/PHP : Is there an equivalent of PHP's array_map() function in C#?

Tags: c#, php, arrays

I've been pondering this today, and I have a nagging feeling that this is something simple to implement and I'm just way out of it today, but anyway, here it is.

Instead of performing something like

```
// assume that I have a populated string[] myString
for (int i = 0; i < myString.Length; i++) {
    myString[i] = myString[i].Equals(string.Empty) ? "foo" : "bar;
}
```

I'd like to do something like PHP's [array_map()](http://nz.php.net/array_map), which (I think) would perform faster than explicit iteration.

Does C# have capacity for this kind of operation?

Comment: Not related to your question, but... there is really no need for `string.Empty` (it’s a remnant from C# 1.0). Use `""`, it’s more readable. Also, when handling strings, you can use `==` instead of `Equals`: it’s exactly equivalent, and it’s also more readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With an extension method:

```
Func<string, string> mapFun = n => n.Equals(string.Empty) ? "foo" : "bar";
Enumerable<string> newNames = names.Select(mapFun);
```

You can also pass `Func` directly:

```
IEnumerable<string> newNames = names.Select(n => n.Equals(string.Empty) ? "foo" : "bar");
```

As seen on [ideone](http://ideone.com/cUL7W). Here are a few other functions that are more or less equivalent:

```
PHP                C#
-------------------------------
array_map()       .Select()
array_filter()    .Where()
array_reduce()    .Aggregate()
```

#### MSDN Reference:

[Enumerable Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341635.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I may have to go with these. :) Much appreciated.

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to my answer, and [Microsoft recommends the Query syntax rather than the extension method syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) used in this answer.

Comment: Instead of dogmatically following some recommendation, I prefer to decide individually what makes more sense. In this simple case here, a single line makes more sense than two lines. In more complex cases, especially when joins are involved, the query syntax is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use one of the Enumerable extension methods. The equivalent of `array_map()` is called `Select()`:

```
var result = array.Select(item => item == "" ? "foo" : "bar");
```

For operations like this, consider using `IEnumerable<T>` more than `T[]` (arrays), but if you already have an array, you can use it because `T[]` actually implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

As a bonus, the equivalent of `array_filter()` is called `Where()`:

```
var nonEmpty = array.Where(item => item != "");
```

If you’re curious what other methods there are, there is [a pretty good list with examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx).

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to my answer, and [Microsoft recommends the Query syntax rather than the extension method syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) used in this answer.

Comment: Instead of dogmatically following some recommendation, I prefer to decide individually what makes more sense. In these simple cases here, a single line makes more sense than two lines. In more complex cases, especially when joins are involved, the query syntax is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

<s>No, because PHP arrays have nothing (!) in common with C# arrays. PHP arrays are hash tables, more like C#'s `System.Collections.Hashtable` or `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<k, v>`.</s> Just realized this doesn't apply here, but it's important nonetheless.

Assuming I'm reading your pseudocode correctly though, you can do what you want with a LINQ query:

```
var result = from item in collection
             select item.Empty() ? "foo" : "bar";
```

I don't see why you'd think something like array_map would be faster than iteration though -- there's going to be iteration going on somewhere, no matter how you look at it. In PHP there's a speed boost from using the builtin function because PHP is interpreted, while the guts of `array_map` are compiled; but C# is a compiled language.

**EDIT**: After reading the docs, it looks like

```
var result = from item in array
             select Callback(item);
```

does essentially what you're looking for. Not sure how to shoehorn the "callback" bit into a function though.

Comment: The callback can just be a function that takes a string as a parameter and returns a string:

private string Callback(string str) { return str.Equals(string.Empty) ? "foo" : "bar"; }

Comment: Yeah, I realized that bit about the iteration thing too, after I got a bit of a nap. Grrr. Thanks, +1 for a very thorough, researched answer. :)

Comment: @smoak: My lack of surety is how to get that callback into the function, not how to actually call the function or what semantics it has.